# amazon multipart upload api for mac

Tags: cocoa, amazon-s3

I'm searching on google from last two days regarding using amazon multipart upload api in my cocoa project for mac. I have downloaded AWS sdk for ios. But didn't find how to use that sdk in cocoa project. Can anyone provide me some example code to achieve multipart uploading using amazon S3 multipart upload???

**Edit:**
As AWS SDK for IOS is not compatible with Cocoa applications, I'm using Rest api to upload file using libcurl. I'm using following code (by taking reference from http://dextercoder.blogspot.in/2012/02/multipart-upload-to-amazon-s3-in-three.html):

```
- (void)initUpload
{
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss "];
    NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GMT", [formatter stringFromDate:now]];
    NSString *strDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@", strDate];
    const char *date = [strDateString UTF8String];

    NSString *stringToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"POST\n\n\n%@\n/MY_BUCKET/test.pdf?uploads",strDate];
    NSString *signature = [self base64forData:[self HMACSHA1withKey:MY_SECRET forString:stringToSign]];
    signature = [signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
    signature = [signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
    signature = [signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
    NSString *strAuthorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Authorization: AWS MY_ACCESSID:%@", signature];
    const char *sig = [strAuthorization UTF8String];

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, date);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, sig);
    CURLcode res;


    if (curlHandle) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/test.pdf?uploads");
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L);            
        res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);       
    }
}

- (NSData *)HMACSHA1withKey:(NSString *)key forString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *clearTextData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

    CCHmacContext hmacContext;
    CCHmacInit(&hmacContext, kCCHmacAlgSHA1, keyData.bytes, keyData.length);
    CCHmacUpdate(&hmacContext, clearTextData.bytes, clearTextData.length);
    CCHmacFinal(&hmacContext, digest);

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}

- (NSString *)base64forData:(NSData *)data
{
    static const char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    if ([data length] == 0)
        return @"";

    char *characters = malloc((([data length] + 2) / 3) * 4);
    if (characters == NULL)
        return nil;
    NSUInteger length = 0;

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (i < [data length])
    {
        char buffer[3] = {0,0,0};
        short bufferLength = 0;
        while (bufferLength < 3 && i < [data length])
        buffer[bufferLength++] = ((char *)[data bytes])[i++];

        //  Encode the bytes in the buffer to four characters, including padding "=" characters if necessary.
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[(buffer[0] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((buffer[1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        if (bufferLength > 1)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[((buffer[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((buffer[2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
        else characters[length++] = '=';
        if (bufferLength > 2)
            characters[length++] = encodingTable[buffer[2] & 0x3F];
        else characters[length++] = '=';        
    }

     return [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:characters length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES] autorelease];
}
```

But its giving response

"< HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
    `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic examples for AWS services like S3, SDB etc provided with the SDK itself:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforios/gsg/Welcome.html?r=1498

Comment: thanks for your reply. There is no example for multipart upload in given samples of SDK that's why I'm asking this. But I have found some code from somewhere else which is given below, but its giving exceptions which are given below. Please check it if you can help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer java code from http://dextercoder.blogspot.in/2012/02/multipart-upload-to-amazon-s3-in-three.html. tells how to upload file in multiparts without AWS.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please check Edit part of my question if you can help me in solving my problem.

Comment: in response you must be getting string that need tobe signed..
just double check the string you are signing is correct.

Comment: I have changed base64 conversion method, now its giving response "HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required". Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: are u setting "Content-Length" in header?

Comment: No I'm not setting Content-Length in header.

Comment: Now I'm trying by setting "Content-Length" in the header but now its giving response that "SignatureDoesNotMatch". I compared signatures created by my program with signatures created by tool provided by amazon at http://aws.amazon.com/code/199 and signatures are same, but its giving response that "SignatureDoesNotMatch". Any idea what is going wrong??